# How to create a Wheat Straw Plastic material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders

I am trying to create this type of Wheat Straw Plastic material and having a short animation where the speckles move. How would be the best accurate form
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this setup. You may modify the colors and noise as per the requirement.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Voronoi Texture will also work:

[image]

Multiple colors of dots:

[image]

[image]

Same color but varying brightness of dots:

[image]

[image]